# Does JPEG Huffman coding use the same Huffman algorithm as the COMPRESS (gzip) algorithm?

Tags: operating-system, jpeg, decode, huffman-code

My question is

Does JPEG Huffman coding use the same Huffman algorithm as the COMPRESS (gzip) algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding#Applications) it is:

> Huffman coding today is often used as a "back-end" to some other compression methods. DEFLATE (PKZIP's algorithm) and multimedia codecs such as JPEG [...]

Deflate/PKZIP is pretty much the same as GZIP (LZ77 + Huffman).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: NO. Long answer: It depends upon what part of the process yo are talking about. The the underling principles are the same but JPEG and PNG do Huffman coding differently. The major difference in how they encode the Huffman tables. The encoding of bits within the stream is the same.

Comment: Good clarification! I'd still argue that the *algorithm* is the same (while the implementation is different).